# Help with finding the associated potential function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following vector field
$$ F = (z^3+x^3,2y,3z^2x)$$

I need to calculate the work from the origin (0,0,0) to the point (2,-1,-2)

I'm not sure if it's correct but I found the associated potential function to be $$z^3x+\frac{1}{4}x^4+2y$$
Which then the work is $$-16+4-2 = -14$$

Comment: Shouldn't your potential function have $y^2$ rather than $2y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, you made a mistake when you calculated the potential function. The function should be:

$$z^3x+\frac{1}{4}x^4+\color{red}{y^2}$$

You can easily check this if you differentiate the function with respect to $x,y,z$.

$\frac{d}{dx}(z^3x+\frac{1}{4}x^4+y^2)=z^3+x^3$

$\frac{d}{dy}(z^3x+\frac{1}{4}x^4+y^2)=2y$

$\frac{d}{dz}(z^3x+\frac{1}{4}x^4+y^2)=3z^2x$

wich yields the vector field you began with.

Comment: didn't even notice this, thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.